How do you connect IP camera to Computer hosted server?
I am programming a client-server architecture and there are many things I still don't understand. I am using this repository from Github as an example to learn this type of programming as I am new to it. However I have trouble understanding how to run this other than just executing the main.py file. How am I supposed to connect my device to the server and allow for access to the camera's live stream?
Edit:
I tried running the server by executing the main.py file. I tried running the telnet <IP address> <port> but I get the following error:
Connecting To 0.0.0.0...Could not open connection to the host, on port 4554: Connect failed
When I change the rtsp_host in the configuration file to anything other than 0.0.0.0 the code doesn't work though. I'm still trying to figure that out but I should be able to connect an IP camera to my server regardless as long as my computer is on the same network as the device, am I right in saying that?

The repository contains an example configuration file. Have you checked that yet? And if yes, what are some more specific problems you have with it? Edit your question to add this information.

Have you followed the step Copy config-example.py to private configuration file _config.py and edit _config.py. as listed in that documentation?

@DanielB well specifically I don't know how to connect anything to the server when it runs. I also don't know how to confirm that the server is running.
